# Transform a representation of bits in a byte array

Tags: java, arrays, byte, bit

I have a set of 1s and 0s as a string in Java:

```
String s = "1101111110000000101010110"
```

How can I transform the representation of a set of bits in a byte array?

Comment: did you try googling your question ??

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
String s = "1101111110000000101010110";
byte[] b = new BigInteger(s, 2).toByteArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply 

As would be the opposite process?, To see if it is doing well

Comment: @user3356062:- I didnt get that!